# Retrieve contentDocument file - REST API

Tags: rest-api, contentdocument

I am trying to pull in an attachment from a case in salesforce to a separate web application. I am able to get the ContentDocument properties but not the actual binary.

Here is the endpoint I am using now to get the properties.

```
/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/ContentDocument/0690n000000A1a1AAC
```

I saw in older posts that when this was stored in the attachments object you could just as /body at the end. That doesn't work for the ContentDocument.

Any direction to documentation would be appreciated.

Comment: pretty sure you have to fetch the contentVersion for that

Comment: @glls and that object connects to the contentDocument I am assuming. I'll take a look at that.

Comment: indeed, via ContentDocumentId

Comment: @glls That looks to be it. Then its the VersionData part of the object? I see a contentBodyId? Also if you put that as an answer, I will accept it. Otherwise I will add the answer myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the the raw data of the document, you actually need to query [ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm), which is related via the ContentDocumentId.

From there, you can access the VersionData field (amongst others)

Comment: i tried accessing services/data/v46.0/sobjects/contentversion/id from external service. It is returning invalid session id.

Answer (score 3):

You got close in your comment to retreiving the file, but if you're going to make a GET request to download it via the API, you need to specify the `VersionData` at the end of the URL, like so:

/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/{{Id}}/VersionData