# Delete ContentDocument through REST API permission

Tags: rest-api, permissions, rest, permission-sets

I'm trying to delete a ContentDocument, added as attachment in an Account, throught REST API. I'm able to retrieve the ContentDocument, Get the Document Data (requesting ContentVersion as described [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/212488/retrieve-contentdocument-file-rest-api)), and then I need to delete this file. But when I make the delete request, I get an **INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY**.

request to:
`https://{{baseurl}}/services/data/v56.0/sobjects/ContentDocument/069DT000001kaAXYAY`

response:

```json
[
    {
        "message": "insufficient access rights on object id",
        "errorCode": "INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY",
        "fields": []
    }
]
```

The user used in the Connected App has a permission set with te following permissions:

[image]

What I'm missing to be able to delete this file?